# Django doesn't take Custom password_reset_form.html

Tags: django, django-3.0

I used a Custom password_reset_form.html

(My Path: /templates/registration/password_reset_form.html)

But Django takes the Django-Default-Password-Reset-View

Any solution what i could do?

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from myapp.CustomForms.appforms import LoginAuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url

from myapp.views import (
...
)


from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 ...
   url(r"^$", views.startseite, name="home"),
   url(r"^signup/$", views.signup, name="signup"),
   url(
   r"^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]. 
   {1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/",
   views.activate, name="activate",),
   url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'myapp',
]
...
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your `urls.py`?

Comment: But how did you set the template of your `PasswordResetView`?

Comment: it works automatically if i set up this path myapp/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html

Comment: @FirmaBuckfink: ok, just want to know how you did set the template (you can also pass this to the `.as_view` of the `PasswordResetView`). Can you share the `TEMPLATES` setting (in `settings.py`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you show how i can pass this with .as_view?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why django didn't pick up my custom template cause i have to change the order of my

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'myapp',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
]
```

myapp has to set before django.contrib.admin and django.contrib.auth